# How do I write a QuickCheck property which expects a non-empty list of non-zero numbers?

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

This is a hack (`cogsRpm` is a user supplied function which is supposed to match the output of go):

```
propCheck ns = cogsRpm (ns ++ [42])  == go (ns ++ [42])
```

I added the 42 to stop quickcheck from generating zero length lists. It also could fail still though because it isn't supposed to have zeroes in there either.

I read the docs, but there are not enough examples for me to parse out how to actually use them. I did manage to get this on another case:

```
prop_check (Positive x) (Positive y)  = updateHealth x y == if y > x then 0 else x-y
```

Which forces positives, and I tried combining a bunch of things to get `listOf1` and `NonZero`, but I could not figure out the syntax, hence the hack to add an element to the list. How can I avoid this hack?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

QuickCheck comes bundled with a [`NonEmptyList`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.11.3/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html#t:NonEmptyList) newtype, whose `Arbitrary` instance only generates non-empty lists. You can combine this with [`NonZero`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.11.3/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html#t:NonZero) to get a non-empty list of non-zero integers:

```
propCheck :: NonEmptyList (NonZero Int) -> Bool
propCheck (coerce -> ns) = cogsRpm ns == go ns
```

I'm using [`coerce`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-Coerce.html#v:coerce) in a [*view pattern*](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#view-patterns) to tersely and efficiently turn the `NonEmptyList (NonZero Int)` back into a regular list of `Int`s.

Comment: Or, for a similarly inscrutable implementation using an import of `Data.Function.on` instead of enabling view patterns: `propCheck ns = ((==) \`on\` ($ coerce ns)) cogsRpm go`